# Remotely deleting registry keys

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete registry keys on a remote PC, but it seems I can't get the path to work correctly.
This is how I get the PC name:

```
$inputPC = Read-Host 'Enter pc name: '
```

And this is the code line I try to delete it with:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputPC -ScriptBlock {
    Remove-ItemProperty-Path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
}
```

Instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` I have tried also `HKLM:` and `HKLM`

I get the error:

```
Cannot find path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...rentVersion\Run:String) [Remove-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : clt64792
```

I understand it does not find the correct path, because it tries to delete it within the folders? How do I then access the registry keys the way I want to do it?

Comment: In that remote pc does this path exists in registry?

Comment: Yes, it does,checked it just now

Comment: Are you trying to remove the *key* or the *property*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Remove-Item` instead of `Remove-ItemProperty`. Hope this works

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $inputPC -ScriptBlock { Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run}
```

Comment: Will test it out in a minute and let You know.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [remote registry API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey) for things like this.

```bsh
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $inputPC)
$reg.DeleteSubKeyTree('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run')
```

Note that the service "RemoteRegistry" must be running for this to work.

Comment: I get an error that: `Exception calling "DeleteSubKeyTree" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist."
At C:\Users\lt2tnv\Documents\Test\5_Deploy\RemovePathsAndRegisry.ps1:26 char:1
+ $reg.DeleteSubKeyTree('\SOFTWARE\test')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException`

Comment: Does the input `'LocalMachine'` define `HKLM`?

Comment: @Tautvis Yes. And you're getting that error b/c you put a backslash before "Software" (wrong: `'\Software\test'`, correct: `'Software\test'`).

Comment: Hi again, I have tried it without backslash, still can not access it. Any suggestions maybe?